# Parsing custom arguments to functions in lua

Tags: lua, coroutine

In this post, I want to know if there is any possible way to pass lua functions with custom arguments in coroutines?

My first guess was trying to do something like that, but then I understood it wouldn't work, and in the end, I stopped there on guessing how to do so.

```lua
function a(a,b)
   print(a+b)
end

b = a(6,3)

coroutine.wrap(b)
```

Comment: Do you mean `b=coroutine.wrap(a); b(6,3)` ?

Comment: nope it's not that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it this what you want?

```
function a(a,b)
   print(a+b)
end

function b()
   a(6,3)
end

coroutine.wrap(b)
```

Comment: The last line returns a function but does not call it